# Подключение библиотеки jzy3d

Tags: java, maven

Всем привет. Такая проблема есть. Нужно для проекта использовать библиотеку jzy3d (для построения графиков, если конкретно).
Не понимаю как подключить библиотеку к проекту.
Везде прочитал, что нужно через Maven, но почитав различные сайты по Maven я так и не допер, как мне ее все таки подключить то?

Ход моих действий: 
На сколько понял нужен Maven -> Создаю новый проект Maven. 
Пишу там код, который нашел [на самом сайте этой библиотеки](http://jzy3d.org/download-1.0.0.php). Сам код -> (возможно написал неправильно, ибо как сказал, не понимаю пока что)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
    <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
            <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

И вот тут собственно вопрос, что мне делать дальше то? Этот код нужно как-то скомпилить (ну или другое действие) ? И как мне ее добавить в мой (другой) проект? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С Maven столкнулся впервые именно в таком виде, выручайте. Если можно то, подробней, ибо понимаю, что пока не вывожу это тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С Maven действительно все непросто, возможностей у него очень много. Для того, чтобы библиотека была у вас в проекте, то в этом проекте тоже нужно использовать Maven. Просто создайте pom в корне Он отлично ляжет в ваш проект, единственное что, нужно будет правильно прописать source directory и java version.

Компилировать и упаковывать тоже желательно через maven, использую mvn clean install. (или compile, или package, это все можно делать и через idea). У вас автоматически будет формироваться jar. Потом, на этапе релиза возможно столкнетесь с shade плагином, который позволит в jar включить зависимости (по умолчанию они не включаются).

Еще плюс - отличная поддержка в idea, вам не нужно ничего в ручную компилировать, просто импортируете maven проект, и уже через зеленую стрелочку он будет прекрасно запускаться.

Есть и альтернативный вариант - в idea в меню project structure можно прейти в artifacts и загрузись либку прямо с мейвен репозитория. А потом подключить ее в modules. Но я этот вариант вам настоятельно не рекомендую, так при загрузке этого всего дела в git repo например, вам снова придется подключать либо через idea (возможно это и можно как то обойти, там создаются свои xml файлики, но лично у меня оно не работало и все приходилось руками делать)

Comment: Если честно, я все равно не очень понял, что мне делать. 
Т.е мне нужно создать просто файл pom.xml в корне проекта, а не целый проект Maven?

Comment: Да, просто создаете pom.xml и прописываете в нем <build> правильные <sourceDirectory> и <directory>. Если я не ошибаюсь, первое у вас будет src, а второе out

Comment: Все понял, спасибо тебе большое. Разобрался. Получилось сделать, то что хотел. Понял,что Maven - мощный и не совсем простой инструмент)